# For an OS X executable, how to display which library an undefined symbol is expected in?

Tags: macos, linker, mach-o, nm, otool

I know how to use nm to display the undefined symbols in a binary.
I also know how to use otool to display which libraries the binary is linked to.

But I don't know how to display for each undefined symbol, which library the linker is expected to find them ?

Note: I am assuming that such information is stored in the mach-o binary, since I have seen before runtime error where dyld would tell you about a missing symbol and pointing out exactly which library it expected to find the symbol in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just missing the use of the `-m` flag to `nm`?

Comment: uh, oh yeah.... I did saw it when I read the man page, but I still could not have guessed...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a shell script to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure a binary file is passed as an argument
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <binary_file>"
    exit 1
fi

binary_file=$1

# Find undefined symbols
undefined_symbols=$(nm -u $binary_file | awk '{print $2}')

# Iterate over undefined symbols
for symbol in $undefined_symbols; do
    # Find the library that contains the symbol
    library=$(otool -L $binary_file | grep $symbol | awk '{print $1}')

    # Print the symbol and the library it belongs to
    echo "$symbol is in $library"
done
```